# Взаимодействие Dragable и sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, drag-n-drop, sortable

http://jsfiddle.net/HappyCougar/DEt6Y/9/

Почему не работает (не крепятся драг элементы)? По коду вроде все правильно. Подскажите пожалуйста, замучился уже искать проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому-что на правом блоке нужно использовать [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/). Вот [пример](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart), посмотрите на него и сделайте аналогично. Если нужно, чтобы из левого блока перетаскивались (а не клонировались) элементы в правый блок, то посмотрите на этот [пример](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager).

Comment: Нужно, что бы клонировался. Возьму за основу данный пример из документации.

Answer (score 0):

По моему, лучше сделать оба блока `sortable` и задать обоим `connectWith`